# Iguana heating lights?

Tags: reptiles, lighting, heaters

I just bought some light to use for my iguanas. Can i use this type of light for heating for the iguana (refer to the picture below):

[image]

I'm not sure whether it produce enough heat or not, but i think it might be too bright.

If this not the one i should use, then what should i use?

Comment: Could you copy all of the information listed on the bulb and/or packaging? We would need to know the exact ratings of the bulb, plus weather it indicates UVA/UVB. To me, your picture is kind of hard to read.